# Looking for everywhere a particular value has been used in foreign keys in one pass

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Good afternoon.

I am using SQL Server 2008/TSQL.  It is probably important to note I do not have write access to any db (I am a read only user).  I do not have write access to the db but can insert temp tables if absolutely needed.

I would like to preface what I am about to say with letting everyone know I have no formal education in SQL.  Hopefully this makes sense - I may be inaccurate in some vocabulary etc.

**Scope of what I am trying to do:
1. Select a specific recordID (value) in a column (primary key) from a table 
2. Find where that specific number/recordID is used in all dependents/foreign keys 
3. Return the tablename and columnname with a count of how many times that value was found**

So, as an example...
You have a table with information on a person tied to a recordID, say something like: 
dbo.MemberInfo with RecordID, Name Etc.

> The ID number of the member (MemberInfo.RecordID) is used in other
>   tables, say: dbo.Awards as [HonoreeID]
>   (dbo.Awards.HonoreeID=MemberInfo.RecordID) dbo.Address as [MemberID]
>   (dbo.Address.MemberID=MemberInfo.RecordID) dbo.Contact as [PersonID]
>   (dbo.Contact.PersonID=MemberInfo.RecordID) ...and potentially a few
>   hundred others

**I basically want to run through all the tables and see how many times a particular value/record is in use.  Now, to add some complexity to this, it needs to be generic, as the column I may be looking up dependents on may change from day to day.  (Ex. I may be looking for dependents of EventID tomorrow)**

My current process is:
-Use a select to find the ID of the person I need
-Look at all the foreign keys linked to RecordID (Primary Key) of dbo.Members
-Dump the tablenames and columns of the foreign keys out into Excel
-Do a find and replace to make a bunch of SELECT COUNTS with a WHERE=@Variable
-Put it into SQL, define my variable and set it equal to the initial ID number

There has to be a better way.  I have attempted many variations of the following with lots of errors and no success:

```
--DECLARE @Selected CHAR
SELECT T.Name, C.Name
--SET @Selected=(SELECT T.Name FROM sys.tables T)
--CASE WHEN (T.NAME IS NOT NULL) THEN 1
--ELSE '0' END AS 'MyTrial'
FROM 
--sys.tables t
sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
WHERE Referenced_Object_ID=--Insert object ID here
```

My line of thinking was/is:
1.  Query foreign keys used in a table/column, return the table name and column name from the dependent tables
2.  Feed these results into something that can build me a new query to return a count of a value in each of the tables/columns where applicable
3.  Return the tablename as well, so it can easily be fed into another select statement should I need to look at the details making up the count.

So my results might look something like this:
Tablename, Columnname, Count of Value in Column

Ideally, no value, table name etc. would be returned if the count is less than one.

My process may be extremely flawed out of the gate, but anything offered helps me learn.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks similiar to this project: [sp_CascadingDataViewer](http://cascadingdataviewer.codeplex.com/) Viewer selects all data, you just need count.

Comment: My initial recommendation is to put off thinking about making it generic for a while. Set a variable and use it to test it successfully. For instance, if I use 462624691 in AdventureWorks, I get Address / StateProvinceID and SalesTaxRate/ StateProvinceID. So then I have to ask myself if that's the data I'm looking for. Then tweak it until I get what I want. It would help to see an example of the current query and process.

Answer (score 0):

The script below uses no stored procedures but does use a temporary table. As far as I can conceive, there's no way around it. It runs very quickly for me, although I was working with a relatively small test database.

This is my first venture into dynamic SQL, so I can't testify to the safety of this code against SQL injection attacks and such. I, too, am self-taught.

```
Declare @Primary_Table varchar(100) = '';
Declare @Column_Name varchar(100) = '';
Declare @Specific_Value int = ;

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Selected_Tables') is not null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Selected_Tables;
End

Select Distinct T.Name as Table_Name
    , C.Name as Column_Name
    , CAST(null as bigint) as Referenced_Records

Into #Selected_Tables

FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t 
        ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c 
        ON fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id 
            AND fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    Inner Join sys.tables AS t2 
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = t2.object_id
    Inner Join sys.columns AS c2 
        on fk.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id

Where t2.name = @Primary_Table
    and c2.Name = @Column_Name;

Declare @sqlCommand nvarchar(max);
Declare @Unprocessed_Records int = (Select Count(1) 
                                    From #Selected_Tables 
                                    Where Referenced_Records is null);
Declare @Processing_Table varchar(1000) = (Select Top 1 Table_Name
                                            From #Selected_Tables
                                            Where Referenced_Records is null);
Declare @Processing_Column varchar(1000) = (Select Top 1 Column_Name
                                            From #Selected_Tables
                                            Where Referenced_Records is null
                                                and Table_Name = @Processing_Table);

While @Unprocessed_Records > 0
Begin
    Set @sqlCommand = 'Update #Selected_Tables '
                        + 'Set Referenced_Records = (Select Count(1) '
                        + 'From ' + @Processing_Table + ' '
                        + 'Where ' + @Processing_Column + ' = ' + CAST(@Specific_Value as nvarchar(1000)) + ') '
                        + 'Where Table_Name = ''' + @Processing_Table + ''' '
                        + 'and Column_Name = ''' + @Processing_Column + ''';'

    Exec (@sqlCommand);

    Set @Unprocessed_Records = (Select Count(1) 
                                    From #Selected_Tables 
                                    Where Referenced_Records is null);
    Set @Processing_Table = (Select Top 1 Table_Name
                                            From #Selected_Tables
                                            Where Referenced_Records is null);
    Set @Processing_Column = (Select Top 1 Column_Name
                                            From #Selected_Tables
                                            Where Referenced_Records is null
                                                and Table_Name = @Processing_Table);
End;

Select * From #Selected_Tables;
```